# How to track login activity of user in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

How to track login activity of user in Laravel 5.6. I mean to say, I have users and admin. Admin can view the login and logout of users. How can I perform that? Is there any package I can install? Or any other way?

Comment: try it https://github.com/aginev/login-activity

Answer (score 1):

You can use Event service to store user login and logout activity. In the app folder, the **app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php** file exists. Open this file and add these lines.

```
'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
    'App\Listeners\SuccessLogin',
],
'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout' => [
    'App\Listeners\SuccessLogout',
],
```

Now open the terminal and run the following command.

```
php artisan event:generate
```

It will generate two **SuccessLogin** and **SuccessLogout** file in **app/Listeners** folder.
Open these files and you will see a handle function

```
public function handle(Logout $event)
{
    //Place your code here
}
```

For more you can visit here https://onegibi.com/programming/laravel-5-store-user-login-and-logout-activity/